# Search for an exact word in Vim command mode

Tags: vim, search

I want to search for an exact word in Vim in command mode (using Vim command `/wordtosearch`, **NOT** the search of the current word at the cursor using `*` or `#` commands), e.g. I would like to search for an exact word say CIF but I do not want to find CIF_handle or CIF_drv.

How to make Vim search for exact word in the command mode?

(I don't mind the case of the word searched, because I already have `ignorecase` set.)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
/\<your_exact_word\>
```

In other words, enclose your search string between `\<` and `\>`

Comment: @Thanks: workd nicely. Does enclosing the word in \< .. \> make it a regex based search.

Comment: Yes, it's a regex search.

Comment: But what do u do if u need to search for a string like "1...". It will highlight all numbers starting with 1 and not the string with the dots.

Comment: Doesn't work with brackets.

Comment: How do you configure `vim` to behave with an exact word search without needing to wrap it with `\<` and `\>` char. Can `vim` be made to do exact word search by `/eightFoldPaths` ?

Answer (score -1):

I just had tried to use `/\<*\>` to search literally `*` sign in vim,
obviously it also counted space in the list.
here is the possible way to do it in a Very Nomagic way,

```
/\v*
```

for for more detail `:help \V`

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer to the question stated. If you want to *add* information to the accepted answer, you may want to add a comment over there.